# How to add a Label to a DataGridView cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is there any way to insert a Label to DataGridView cell at runtime - say for example I wanted a little red number in the top corner of each cell? Do I need to create a new DataGridViewColumn type or can I just add a Label there when I'm populating the DataGridView?

**EDIT** I am now attempting to do this using Cell painting as per Neolisk's suggestion, but am unsure how to actually get the label to be displayed. I have the following code, where I now add the label text as the cell's `Tag` before setting its `Value`:

```
private void dgvMonthView_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = this.dgvMonthView;
    DataGridViewCell cell = dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];

    Label label = new Label();
    label.Text = cell.Tag.ToString();
    label.Font = new Font("Arial", 5);
    label.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

Can anyone explain how I can now "attach" `label` to `cell`?

**EDIT 2 - Solution** I couldn't quite get it to work the above way, so have ended up subclassing the DataGridViewColumn and Cell and overriding the `Paint` event there to add whatever text is stored in `Tag` using DrawString rather than a Label as per neolisk's suggestion:

```
class DataGridViewLabelCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics,
                                  Rectangle clipBounds,
                                  Rectangle cellBounds,
                                  int rowIndex,
                                  DataGridViewElementStates cellState,
                                  object value,
                                  object formattedValue,
                                  string errorText,
                                  DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
                                  DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
                                  DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        // Call the base class method to paint the default cell appearance.
        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState,
            value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle,
            advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);

        if (base.Tag != null)
        {
            string tag = base.Tag.ToString();
            Point point = new Point(base.ContentBounds.Location.X, base.ContentBounds.Location.Y);
            graphics.DrawString(tag, new Font("Arial", 7.0F), new SolidBrush(Color.Red), cellBounds.X + cellBounds.Width - 15, cellBounds.Y);
        }
    }
}

public class DataGridViewLabelCellColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public DataGridViewLabelCellColumn()
    {
        this.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewLabelCell();
    }
}
```

Implemented as:

```
DataGridViewLabelCellColumn col = new DataGridViewLabelCellColumn();
dgv.Columns.Add(col);
col.HeaderText = "Header";
col.Name = "Name";
```

Comment: Have you tried custom cell painting? You should be able to accomplish any kind of custom drawing, including a small label in the corner. [See this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/07071c24-d0c4-4952-8e53-fe0d2bf20641).

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like it could be ideal however still not sure how to actually add the Label. I've updated my question with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing custom painting, you should be using [Graphics.DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring.aspx) instead of `Label` control. Your `e` is of type `DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs`, so it has `Graphics` property. Here is an example of using [PaintEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76c5db29.aspx), yours should be similar.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I have used the DrawString method, and updated my question with the solution

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx?PHPSESSID=o1fb21liejulfgrptbmi9dec92) is an MSDN tutorial on how to host a control in a Winforms DataGridViewCell.

just follow the procedures of label

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however this only seems to cover how to override the editing control, but I need the label to always be displayed. I've updated my question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this could solve your problem

```
 class LabelColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public LabelColumn()
        : base(new LabelCell())
    {
    }
    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null &&
            !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(LabelCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a CalendarCell");
            }
            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }
}
public class LabelCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public LabelCell()
        : base()
    {
    }
    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);
        LabelEditingControl lb = DataGridView.EditingControl as LabelEditingControl;
        if (this.Value == null)
        {
            lb.Value = this.DefaultNewRowValue;
        }
        else
        {
            lb.Value = this.Value;
        }
    }
    public override Type EditType
    {
        get
        {
            // Return the type of the editing control that CalendarCell uses.
            return typeof(LabelEditingControl);
        }
    }

    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get
        {
            // Return the type of the value that CalendarCell contains.

            return typeof(string);
        }
    }
    public override object DefaultNewRowValue
    {
        get
        {
            // Use the "".
            return "";
        }
    }
    class LabelEditingControl : Label, IDataGridViewEditingControl
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView;
        private bool valueChanged = false;
        int rowIndex;
        public Object Value { get; set; }
        public LabelEditingControl()
        {
            this.Enabled = false;
        }
        public object EditingControlFormattedValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Value.ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                if (value is String)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // This will throw an exception of the string is 
                        // null, empty, or not in the format of a date.
                        this.Value = value;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        // In the case of an exception, just use the 
                        // default value so we're not left with a null
                        // value.
                        this.Value = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
        {
            return EditingControlFormattedValue;
        }
        public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(
    DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
        {
            this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
            this.ForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor;
            this.BackColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor;
        }
        public int EditingControlRowIndex
        {
            get
            {
                return rowIndex;
            }
            set
            {
                rowIndex = value;
            }
        }
        public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(
   Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
        {
            // Let the DateTimePicker handle the keys listed.
            switch (key & Keys.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Left:
                case Keys.Up:
                case Keys.Down:
                case Keys.Right:
                case Keys.Home:
                case Keys.End:
                case Keys.PageDown:
                case Keys.PageUp:
                    return true;
                default:
                    return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
            }
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit 
        // method.
        public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
        {
            // No preparation needs to be done.
        }
        public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
        // .EditingControlDataGridView property.
        public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
        {
            get
            {
                return dataGridView;
            }
            set
            {
                dataGridView = value;
            }
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
        // .EditingControlValueChanged property.
        public bool EditingControlValueChanged
        {
            get
            {
                return valueChanged;
            }
            set
            {
                valueChanged = value;
            }
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
        // .EditingPanelCursor property.
        public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Cursor;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

on form write this code

```
 LabelColumn clm = new LabelColumn();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(clm);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(5);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells[0].Value ="hello"; //or do anything desired
        }
```